# 3 Array convertir a uno

Tags: php, mysql, array

Hola buenas tengo una consulta donde pregunto por las cantidades en 3 diferentes tablas pero con distintas condiciones.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM( d.cantidad ) AS sumtotal , 
d.op, d.item FROM cc_despacho AS d WHERE d.Estado NOT LIKE  'DESPACHADO'
GROUP BY d.OP,d.Item ORDER BY d.OP";

$array1 = array();
$resultado = mysqli_query($ConexionMYSQL, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
      $array1[]=$row ;
}

$sql2 = "SELECT SUM( d.cantidad ) AS sumtotal , 
d.op, d.item FROM cc_inventario AS d GROUP BY d.OP,d.Item ORDER BY d.OP";
$array2 = array();
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($ConexionMYSQL, $sql2);

    while ($roww = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)) {
      $array2[]=$roww;
}

$sql3 = "SELECT SUM( d.cantidad ) AS sumtotal , 
d.op, d.item FROM cc_packing AS d GROUP BY d.OP,d.Item ORDER BY d.OP";
$array3 = array();
$resultado3 = mysqli_query($ConexionMYSQL, $sql3);

    while ($rowww = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado3)) {
      $array3[]=$rowww;
}
```

Mi pregunta si esta la forma de poder correr estos 3 array y sumar sus cantidades deacuerdo al mismo op y item y esto poder grabarlo en un string de la siguente forma, para luego mostrarlo en una tabla.

```
$tabla.='{"op":"'.$op.'","item":"'.$item.'","sumtotal":"'.$sumtotal.'"},';
```

Espero haberme explicado bien. No se si es la mejor forma de hacerlo, ya que no tengo mucho conocimiento en SQL.

Comment: si son la misma cantida de columnas puedes hacer una sola consulta usando UNION ALL

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez Gracias por tu ayuda